# Separability of a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a class of subsets of a space $X$ and $B:=\sigma(E)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $E$, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $E$. Let $x,y \in X$ be such that for all $A \in E$, either $\{x,y\} \in A$ or $\{x,y\} \in A^\mathsf{c}$ holds. Prove that the last statement holds for $B$ as well, i.e. 
$$C \in B \Rightarrow \{x,y\} \in C \text{ or } \{x,y\} \in C^\mathsf{c}$$

Here is my attempt, which is rife with mathematical inaccuracies. I hope someone can correct it.

Take $D := 2^E$, which is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains both $E$ and $B$. Now take $C \in D$. Since $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, there must exist a sequence $C_i$ such that
$$ \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty C_i = C$$
and either $C_i \in E$ or $C_i = \emptyset$ holds. Now suppose that $\{x,y\} \not\subseteq C$. Then it holds for all $i$ that $\{x,y\} \not\subseteq C_i$. From this I conclude that the complements of all $C_i$'s (with respect to $E \cup \emptyset$) must contain $\{x,y\}$. Therefore, their intersection $C^\mathsf{c}$ contains $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Why do you take $C \in D$? You have to show that the statement holds for $C \in B$ ...

Comment: @saz If I just replace $D$ with $B$, then does the proof still make sense? I thought I needed the power set first and then I would argue that since $B$ is contained in $D$, this implication must be true for $B$ as well but now that I think about it again, it doesn't quite add up in my head.

Comment: The claim does not hold for $D$. The problem is that (in general) there does not exist a representation of the form $$C = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i.$$

Answer (score 2):

We put $F= \{ H \cup K: H \in \{\{x,y\}, \emptyset\}, K \in Powerset(X \setminus \{x,y\})\}$.

We have $B=\sigma(E) \subseteq F$ because $E \subseteq  F$ and $F$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$.

Since  the $\sigma$-algebra   $F$  has the  property that $A \in F \rightarrow \{x,y\} \subseteq A ~\text{or} ~ \{x,y\} \subseteq A^c$, we claim that the similar property has $B$.

Comment: Could you explain your last statement a bit? I don't see why it needs to hold for $B$ as well.

Comment: $B$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras which contain the class $E$. This means that $B$  coincides with some subclass $F_1$ of $F$  because $F$ is $\sigma$-algebra and contains the class $E$. This implies that if $A \in F_1$ then $F_1$ also contains $A^c$. But they both $A$ and $A^c$  again are in $F$ and so have the required property.

Comment: Ok I get it but now the $F$ you constructed is not a $\sigma$-algebra I think. It contains the empty set but $X$ is not in it.

Comment: Hint: Take $H=\{x,y\}$ and $K=X \setminus \{x,y\}$.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I see it now.